# Get selected option for dynamic selects

Tags: angular

I am getting a dynamic number of dropdowns in my application. For example i am getting two dropdowns

[image]

Since I have a dynamic set of selects, I need to be able to capture the selected value, which I can  see in my console. The problem is, if we select `March` and `2017` for the year, I need to be able to capture both values when the form is submitted. How can I do that if I have `(change)="onChange($event.target.value)"`  for all selects ? I can't just assign these values to two local variables because I might have many selects like : `month`,`year`,`company`,`client`....

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row  left" *ngFor='let control of tabControls; let i = index' style="padding-bottom:3px">
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-left" style="border:0px dotted">
        {{control.DropDownTitle}}:
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-left">
       <select [(ngModel)]="selected[i]" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" style="width:80%">
          <option value="?" >Please Select</option>
          <option selected *ngFor='let controlList of control.DropdownValues' [ngValue]="controlList.Value">
            {{controlList.Value}}
          </option>
       </select>
   </div>
```

**TS:**

```
selected: any[] = [];
onChange(selected: any) {
  console.log('selected item ' + selected);
}
```

### UPDATE, tried the following:

**HTML**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)">
   <div class="row  left" *ngFor='let control of tabControls; let i = index' style="padding-bottom:3px">
      <div class="col-lg-2 text-left" style="border:0px dotted">
         {{control.DropDownTitle}}:
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-pull-3 text-left">
         <select  style="width:80%" name="hhh">
            <option value="?">Please Select</option>
            <option selected *ngFor='let controlList of control.DropdownValues'>
                {{controlList.Value}}
            </option>
         </select>
         <button type="submit">Submit Values</button>
      </div>
</form>
<pre>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

Component

```
tabControls: ITabControls[];        
submit(val:any) {
  console.log("values: ", val)
}
```

output

[image]

console

[image]

**Intefaces:**

```
export interface ITabControls {
    DropdownValues: Array<IDropdownValues>
    DropDownID: number;
    DropDownTitle: string;
    IsMonth: boolean;
    IsYear: boolean;
    IsCompay: boolean;
    IsReportName: boolean;
}

export interface IDropdownValues {
    DropDownID: number;
    DropDownMappingID: number;
    Value: string;
}
```

JASON

```
[


  {
    "DropdownValues": [
      {
        "DropDownID": 1,
        "DropDownMappingID": 1,
        "Value": "January"
      },
      {
        "DropDownID": 1,
        "DropDownMappingID": 3,
        "Value": "February"
      },
      {
        "DropDownID": 1,
        "DropDownMappingID": 4,
        "Value": "March"
      }


    ],
    "DropDownID": 1,
    "DropDownTitle": "Month",
    "IsMonth": true,
    "IsYear": false,
    "IsCompay": false,
    "IsReportName": false
  },
  {
    "DropdownValues": [
      {
        "DropDownID": 2,
        "DropDownMappingID": 14,
        "Value": "2016"
      },
      {
        "DropDownID": 2,
        "DropDownMappingID": 15,
        "Value": "2017"
      },
      {
        "DropDownID": 2,
        "DropDownMappingID": 16,
        "Value": "2018"
      },
      {
        "DropDownID": 2,
        "DropDownMappingID": 17,
        "Value": "2019"
      },
      {
        "DropDownID": 2,
        "DropDownMappingID": 18,
        "Value": "2020"
      }
    ],
    "DropDownID": 2,
    "DropDownTitle": "Year",
    "IsMonth": false,
    "IsYear": true,
    "IsCompay": false,
    "IsReportName": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide plunker.

Comment: can't you get all the selected values out of the `selected` array?

Comment: yes I can, but the selected array gets reset every time i change my selection. I can do it by creating another Array and push the values in the array. The issue with that is it gets rally messy foe example if i select March for month then change it April , i will have both values in the array

Comment: @rgoal Hey, you have evolved! This question is good, problem clearly stated etc. This is a compliment, not a sarcastic comment :) +1 for that ;) And yes, this comment is totally useless so I will delete it later :D

Comment: @AJT_82  learned from you :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you actually wrap this in a form (if it's possible in your use case) This is by far the best solution in my mind, since you have dynamic values and don't know them beforehand. The form works well with that, and you can easily compose an object with your values to work with! At the same time you can "get rid off" all those ngModels etc, which makes it cleaner, if you of course do not NEED them.

So do something like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)">
<div *ngFor='let control of tabControls; let i = index'> 
   <div>
      {{control.DropDownTitle}}:
   </div>
   <div>
      <select name="{{control.DropDownTitle}}" ngModel>
         <option *ngFor='let controlList of control.DropdownValues'>
            {{controlList.Value}}
         </option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit Values</button>
</form>
```

This will create a nice object, something like this:

```
{
  "Month": "February",
  "Year": "2017"
}
```

which you can work with. This of course changes constantly dynamically if you make changes. And if you do not wish to have a submit button for this, you can solve it any way you like, but knowing you have all values in `myForm.value`-object :)

**Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aqfVyu1nNvHLw65rEBUu?p=preview)**

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT:**

You can access your Object values the easiest by using `Object.values`, which creates a nice array:

```
console.log(Object.values(theObject));
```

that would output e.g:

```
["February", "2017"]
```

Object values might not be supported everywhere, so the safest bet would probably be to use this:

```
for (let p in theObject) {
   console.log("property: ", p, " , value: ", theObject[p]);
}
```

which would give you something like:

```
property: Month, value: February
property: Year, value: 2017
```

Comment: it did not work, updated my above code. I think this is due to using an interface , this is why the object is not printing in the screen or console

Comment: Interface has nothing to do with this. This seems to be a problem of how your data is built. In my plunker I just "assumed" how your `tabControls` array looks like, apparantly it is different from yours, which causes the `object Object` error. As you can see, the interface does not matter: https://plnkr.co/edit/aqfVyu1nNvHLw65rEBUu?p=preview Could you please post your incoming data. According to your interfaces my solution should work as is, when looking at the build of the JSON, i.e your Interfaces. Hmm. But paste your incoming JSON please, or better yet, create a plunker :)

Comment: ... and another tip. Please, if you try some solution e.g by answer provided. Add that update to your question as an **Update**, since for future reference, when someone stumbles upon your question, the original issue should be clearly stated in question. Otherwise e.g in this case someone would wonder why I have given an answer that you already have stated in your original question ;) This time I edited your question for you :)

Comment: @AJT-82  make sense thanks for doing that, added my jason ubove

Comment: Copied your exact JSON to the plunker, works wonderfully, as you can see! https://plnkr.co/edit/LfwcQetcO4s1LG896LWJ?p=preview I can't think of anything more now to suggest... :( Could you please try and recreate the issue in a plunker? Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: One more thing I could think of, is that if you are using an older version of Angular where `ngModel` is not supported, you could try and use `[ngModel]="''"` instead, i.e setting it as empty. So try this forked plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/fjjdbIl2eexyQj3bVfRW?p=preview

Comment: hummm I am using angular 2 , npm 4.2.0 and core-js 2.4.1. ngModel is working ...I think it has to do with the component.html  calling the tab.component.html which contains the form..I have to create a plunker , it will take me a bit of time...

Comment: finally got it :)  it was related to something else other than your answer.. your solution is great :) one final thing now that I have the object , how can I loop through the object , {month:april, year:2016} how can april and 2016 to do something with it?

Comment: Well goooood that it got sorted out. Was wondering myself that what the heck could be wrong :D As to the question about the object, it's basically plain JS. I updated my answer with examples! :)

Comment: Thank YOU Very MUCH